# android image size with mdpi ldip hdpi xdpi

Tags: android

I have  put 4 image for each folder mdpi,ldpi,hdpi,xdpi in the ratio of 3:4:6:8.

Now I need to make any changes in androidmanifieast.xml file or application automatic select from which folder he need to pick up proper image according to screen resolution of device?

Thank You.

Comment: what is your question ? Don't understand.

Comment: @ChiragRaval I want to use hdpi,ldpi xdpi folder where I have put image which I want to use. what are the steps for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Now I need to make any changes in androidmanifieast.xml
```

you have to add this code in manifest.xml file

```
<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"/>
```

application automatically pick up proper image according to screen resolution..